# Deriving the catenary from a hanging chain

Tags: physics, arc-length

Assume a heavy chain (constant mass per unit length) takes the shape of a plane curve $\mathcal C$ after being suspended by its two ends from the same height. Let $s$ be its arc length starting from its lowest point, let $T$ be the tension in the chain, let $\varphi$ be the angle between the tangent line and the horizontal, and let $\lambda$, $\mu$ be two non-zero constants.

I'm trying to show that $T\cos \varphi = \lambda $ and $T\sin \varphi = \mu s$.

Just as a gut check, if we plug in $s=0$ where the tangent line is horizontal so $\varphi = 0$, we find that $T=\lambda\neq 0$, but to me the tension in the chain at its lowest point or where $s=0$ should be zero since there is no chain below it to hold up.

Without solving the problem for me here, where am I going wrong?

Comment: $\lambda$ represents the force in the horizontal direction. At the lowest point, it is not zero. Intuitively, the chain is stretched at any point. At the lowest point, the stretch happens to be horizontal.

Comment: @FellowInstituteOfMathophile that confuses me given this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386596.

This is what I came up with when I thought about the problem. At $s=0$, we're considering an infinitesimally small point so no tension should act on it.

Comment: @FellowInstituteOfMathophile I think in that post they are just talking about vertical forces. At $s=0$ we would have the tension forces being horizontal.

Comment: @Bifton Mifts You can see intuitively why there must be positive tension in the chain at the lowest point by considering what must happen if you were to cut the chain at that point. If there were no tension there, then neither half of the chain would be exerting any force on the other half. Thus, if you were to cut the chain at that point, the configuration of the two halves of the chain shouldn't change.  This is obviously wrong, since the two halves of the chain would actually fall away from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a free body diagram of forces. Consider the portion of the chain between the lowest point and another point P above.

Tension T at P above is inclined, so has two components. One vertical component $Q=T\sin\varphi$ is balanced  by the chain weight and  the horizontal component of chain weight $T\cos \varphi$ is counteracted or balanced by *an always constant non-zero horizontal force* at P = H say.

The differential equation of catenary is
$$ \tan \varphi= \frac{Q}{H}=\frac{\mu s}{H}~$$
if $\mu$ is the chain weight per unit arc length. Hope you take it from there.